# PHP codesniffer path to whole project

Tags: php, composer-php, phpcodesniffer

I`m new to this but i have installed composer and with it installed PHP Codesniffer.
Now, how can i use php codesnifer to check for files in my entire project folder?
My directory structure is something like this:

```
ProjectName
    functions
        functions.php
    templates
        template.php
    myFunctions.php
    vendor
        bin
            phpcs.exe
```

If i try to run

```
phpcs --standard=PSR2 functions
```

it will check the files inside of the functions files inside of the functions directory but i need it to check all the php files in the ProjectName directory.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `phpcs --standard=PSR2 /path/to/ProjectName` or even changing into the ProjectName folder and running `phpcs --standard=PSR2 .`? If you want to exclude the `vendor` dir, make sure you also use `--ignore=*/vendor/*`. Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there should be an option called "extensions" to fit your use

```
phpcs --extensions=php --standard=PSR2 .
```

where you should run this code in your project root directory since "." points to the current directory

Answer (score 4):

You can use dot sign "." to check [current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4898031/1348344).

```
phpcs --standard=PSR2 .
```